# Iterator substring in file listing loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
for %%a in (*.en.srt) do (
   echo %%~na
)
```

This script lists all files with `.en.srt` ending but without extension (`.srt`).

**How to get substring which does not contain .en part as well?**

I tried to apply this advice:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#Snippets.MidString

but I can't get this working for `%%a` and `%%~na` variable.

Apparently I don't understand batch syntax basics so now I'm asking for help here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the characters after the last `.` in the name are considered to be part of the extension. All characters before the last `.` (including any additional `.`) are considered to be part of the base name.

You can use a second FOR loop to strip off the `.en`

```
for %%a in (*.en.srt) do for %%b in ("%%~na") do echo %%~nb
```

If you have a file named `part1.part2.en.srt`, then it will echo `part1.part2`. If you want only the characters before the first `.`, then you can use a FOR /F loop.

```
for %%a in (*.en.srt) do for /f "eol=. delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do echo %%b
```

However, the above will fail if the file name is `.en.srt`. **EDIT:** That can be fixed with a trivial modification.

```
for %%a in (*.en.srt) do for /f "eol=. delims=." %%b in ("\%%a") do echo(%%~nb
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution for doing what I'd been trying to accomplish! And it's kind of tricky ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact it will always be .en

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.en.srt) do (
    set tempstr=%%~na
    set tempstr=!tempstr:.en=!
    echo !tempstr!
)
```

Or you can delim by period if you know none of the filenames have a period otherwise.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B *.en.srt') do echo %%a
```

**Edit**

Changed the code for clarity, also to answer your comment, this would work:

```
for %%a in (*.en.srt) do (
    set tempstr=%%~na
    set tempstr=!tempstr:.en=!
    del !tempstr!
)
```

Comment: Considering first snippet how to use tempstr variable in some other commands other than echo? e.g. del "c:/!tempstr!" or "c:/%tempstr" does not work for me... What I'm trying to accomplish is delete all subtitles files when corresponding movies are missing (but they does not contain .en string within the name)